# WordPress: how to open the_content() in a lightbox or new window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shadowbox

I´m trying to open the_content (just pictures) in a lightbox. 
I´d like a page like a Christmas-calendar so that you can see the posts (and the planned too) and if you click the published post, the image (the_content) should be shown in a shadowbox, lightbox or whatever, I think you´ll know what I mean. Right now my code looks like:

```
<header class="entry-header" rel="shadowbox" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink();?>';"  style="cursor:pointer;">
        <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail();
        endif; ?>

        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <div class="kalender">
                <p1> <?php the_field('nummer'); ?> </p1>
                <br>
                <p2><?php the_time('j. F Y'); ?> </p2> 
            <p3><?php the_title(); ?></p3>

             </div>
            <!-- .comments-link -->
        <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
    </header>
```

I think the easiest way would be to handle the_content like a read_more link and just say onclick show in an shadowbox. But right now I just don't know how to. You can have a look [here](http://mh.weitweitweg.in) (right now just in Firefox or Safari, don't know why Chrome hates me:-))

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Fancybox plugin: http://fancybox.net/howto

Then include an anchor tag in each of your posts, like 'read more', with the content's unique ID:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#content">Read More - This shows content of element who has id="content"</a>
```

Just ensure that each post's #content DIV has a unique ID, increment a variable in your loop and append it to read something along the lines of:

```
#content-01, content-02, etc.
```

Then just hide the content DIV's with CSS.

```
.fancybox { display: none; }
```

P.S. seems fine in Chrome 34.0.1847.131

Comment: hi Scott, thx for your reply.
so you would ad an anchor tag in each post? normally i just want to drop the jpg in, set the date and thats it. 
Sorry normally i would test longer, but in this case its a matter of time :-)

Comment: Yes, you'd have to add an anchor tag to achieve your desired goal. You could wrap it around a thumbnail or some text. I think the 'read more' approach you mentioned above is the way to go. You could also just wrap the entire post in an anchor tag...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful pattern to pass server-side data to the client-side:
 1. Use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to output a script fragment to the DOM.
 2. Inside that script fragment, assign the value of `the_content` to a
    JavaScript global string variable.
 3. Use this JavaScript global from
    inside your JavaScript to read the value of `the_content`

Comment: hey buley thx for your respond.
Sorry but I didnt´t get the idea behind, maybe its cause i´m not so deep in coding. Would you mind telling me more specific? Whats the DOM and how can I Output a script to these DOM? sorry:)

Comment: Hello - I'm unable to spend the time to answer those questions. They are very basic concepts and already well-covered elsewhere.